# My software sources are selected as ubuntu old version 12.something while installing adobe reader

Tags: command-line, flash

My software sources are selected to an old version of ubuntu while installing the adobe reader and im using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.now i am getting a notification in the above system tray that says "The update information is outdated.This may be caused by network problems or by the repositary that is no longer available.............."
and i am getting the following errors in sudo apt-get update
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tahutek-team/prozilla/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tahutek-team/prozilla/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
unfortunately i cant post more than 2 links
I want to fix this the other questions related to mine...doesn't really solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the source.list file whit thunar, and use system settings and enter update, and hatch to to first option and reload, and then try to install it again, and it might work fine this way.